# Heroku Postgres `pg:kill` error: column "nan" does not exist

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

I am trying to use the command `heroku pg:kill postgresql-xxx-xxx --app my-app` to kill database connections but I'm getting the following strange error:

```
ERROR:  column "nan" does not exist
LINE 2: SELECT pg_cancel_backend(NaN);
                                 ^
 !    psql exited with code 1
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The [`heroku pg:kill` command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-pg-kill-pid-database) expects a [process ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) (PID):

```
heroku pg:kill PID [DATABASE]
```

Process IDs are numeric, but you are giving it a string `postgresql-xxx-xxx`.

That can't be converted to a number, but it looks like the Heroku CLI doesn't realize that and is trying to send `NaN` (not a number, likely the result of running `Number("postgresql-xxx-xxx")`) to the underlying [PostgreSQL `pg_cancel_backend()` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL).

Note that this command doesn't kill all database connections, but rather kills one running query. To use it you'll need to provide the numeric PID of the query you wish to kill. You can see running queries using [`heroku pg:ps`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-pg-ps-database).

To kill *all* connections I think you want [`heroku pg:killall`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-pg-killall-database).